# VB6 DATA REPORT FILE

Tags: vb6

Please i would want to know what kind of VB6 file(s) that generates a data report? Example vb common dialog is generated by COMDLG32.OCX, vb datagrid is generated by MSDATGRD.OCX, microsoft data report designer v6.0 is generated by MSDBRPT.DLL

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you are looking for [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248055).
As per the article, the name of the underlying dll is **Msdbrptr.dll**.